# SQL Server 2005 or Visual Studio 2005 - writing my first procedure, any tips or good starting points?

Tags: sql-server-2005, stored-procedures, visual-studio-2005

I'm about to write my first procedure to check if yesterdays data exists in one database, and if it select some of the data, use a count and insert that data into another database. If the data doesn't exist, then send me an email.

I'm using SQL Server 2005 and I'd like to ask the community for tips or good starting knowledge on smart procedure coding.

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Here is an [article on MSDN about stored procedures on SQL Serve 2005](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms190782%28SQL.90%29.aspx) that should help.